# insertFileFromBase64 & insertOoxml not working as expected in Word Online Office JS

Tags: javascript, ms-word, base64, office-js, openxml

Hey StackOverflow Community,

I'm facing an issue with two methods, "insertOoxml" and "insertFileFromBase64," which are working perfectly in Word Offline but not in Word Online API.

**Method Name : insertOoxml & insertFileFromBase64**

**Sample Code**
Note: this is just given for reference.

```
            var range = context.document.getSelection();
            range.insertFileFromBase64(base64, Word.InsertLocation.replace);  
                                // or
            range.insertOoxml(ooXML, Word.InsertLocation.replace);
            let clauseCC = range.insertContentControl();
            range.select();
```

Output :
Offline Word: Both methods insert the file content as expected.
Online Word:  The methods insert the content control and add placeholder text like "Click here to add text." However, after some time, they add the content of the document, which is not smooth and not in the exact place. Sometimes, it doesn't insert any content at all, even after waiting.

I've attached a screenshot for reference. You can also check the issue on GitHub:https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/819
[image: Word Online Error Office JS]

I'd appreciate any insights, suggestions, or possible solutions to resolve this inconsistency in Word Online API. Your help would be highly valuable.

Thank you in Advance!

Hardik Shah

Happy Coding!

Comment: A difference in behavior across platforms is usually a bug. I think you should create a new issue on the office-js repo, but include a link to the older issue.